# simple c++ loop prefix postfix operator

Tags: c++, loops, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int j = 5;
    while ( ++j < 9)
        cout << j++ << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So I am working on a book, and I understand how these things work, but I am seeking a more concrete explanation of why this prints 6 and 8. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Pre-increment and post-increment... not too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
int j = 5;
while ( ++j < 9)
    cout << j++ << endl;
```

Why are only `6` and `8` printed?

Upon entering the loop, `j` is 5. Then the `while (++j ...` increments that to 6. Then the `cout` executes, printing out 6. Then the side effect of the `j++` takes place, incrementing it to 7.

On the next iteration of the loop, the `++j` increments it again, giving `8`, which is then printed out. Then the side effect of the `j++` takes place, incrementing `j` to 9.

Then when `while (++j < 9)` is executed again, `j` has been incremented to 10, so the `while` loop exits, and no more is printed.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what it outputs you need to step through the code:

```
j = 5
j = j + 1 // 6
j < 9 ? yes
output j // 6
j = j + 1 // 7
go to start of loop
j = j + 1 // 8
j < 9 ? yes
output j // 8
j = j + 1 // 9
go to start of loop
j = j + 1 // 10
j < 10 ? no
```

Answer (score 1):

`j` starts as 5. It then gets incremented to 6, then compared with 9 in in `++j < 9`. This passes the condition, so we go to the next line, where it outputs 6 and then increments `j` to 7. We go back to the conditional, `j` is incremented to 8, which is still less than 9, then output, then `j` is incremented to `9`, where the condition fails and the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

++j means the value of j is incremented by 1 *and then* used in the expression where it appears

j++ means the (*current*) value of j is used in the expression, *after that* j is incremented

Answer (score 0):

++j means increase j by one and then evaluate j.
j++ on the other hand means evaluate j first and then increase it by 1.